# Delete a photo asset with setImageData: does not work on iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, assets, alassetslibrary

I am trying to remove a photo from assets using `setImageData:nil` method like below:

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
     NSLog(@"asset url: %@", asset.defaultRepresentation.url);
     if(asset.isEditable) {
          [asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Asset url %@ should be deleted. (Error %@)", assetURL, error);
          }];
     }
}];
```

The photo has been saved with the same app so I understand this should be possible, but it is not removed from the photo library and it does not give any error. The first `NSLog` prints the correct `assetURL` but when `setImageData` is called the `assetURL` is null.

> asset url: assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=4B782AD1-30CF-4EDD-8879-CE262E6BE884&ext=PNG
>
> Asset url (null) should be deleted. (Error (null))

Using this method to delete an image has been deprecated in recent iOS releases or what is the cause of it not working?